# Dynamic link to perform javascript and JSON log in

Tags: javascript, web, href, mobile-application

If I seem short, sorry, but I am having difficulty describing how I am to make an operation through a shared link.

How would I make a function in a javascript to open a dynamic link such as

```
mycompany.com/?l_id=150#signin
```

where the id will give a user an item to call.

How do I make the program start with ?l_id=150 because upon clicking the link
it gives me the address

```
mycompany.com/#signin
```

Comment: Are-you looking for something like `window.location`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, not sure what that is but I will posy my solution below. can you explain what window.location is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tolokaban was right, but here is the actual function if anyone needs it.

```
    function queryToObject(){
        var l, o = {}, q = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
        q = q.split("&");
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            l = q[i].split("=");
            if(!l[0]) continue;
            o[l[0]] = l[1];
        }
        return o;
    }
```